# user_friends facebook permission removed without action

Tags: facebook

I have an app on android and ios that uses facebook login. A few times I noticed a weird thing: the friends permission was not there, even though I never actively removed it in facebook settings.

E.g. on Android I login with

```
    final List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();
    permissions.add("public_profile");
    permissions.add("user_friends");
    permissions.add("email");
```

LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(_activity, permissions);

everything is fine, on callback I see the token with all permissions. After some days I start the app and AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() only has public_profile, email and contact_email (whatever that is), but no user_friends.
I could not reproduce that intentionally and it does not happen all the time, but I've seen it with 3 different test users so far (one time with each).

Did anybody else encounter that? Do you have any idea how could that happen?

To my knowledge, there are two ways how the permissions can be removed: 1) inside facebook settings -> apps -> choose the app and edit settings  2) uncheck the permission inside that small facebook view during the app login .
My test users did neither of that.

Comment: Permissions can also be revoked via API - but either your app, or the users would have to actively do that as well. / If this is not reproducible, there’s little chance of figuring out what is going on. Are those users you know personally, and that have a developer/tester background? Otherwise, I would tend to rather attribute it to them having removed the permission themselves (or not granted it in the first place) … and now having trouble remembering it, as less tech-savvy people sometimes tend to ;)

Comment: CBroe, the users are me and my colleagues, so it's unlikely that all of us removed the permissions without realising that :) I don't know if that ever happened to the real app users, hopefully it did not.

Comment: Ok, fair enough :) If you can manage to reproduce this in a reliable manner somehow, file a bug report. But without, there’s little chance IMHO.